# HTML Line break in a href affects other non link text for puppeteer

Tags: html, css, pdf, href, puppeteer

i have the following problem. I have a text followed up by a link. If the link is in one line everything is ok but if it breaks into 2 lines the a - area gets over the first text so the complete 2 lines and I can click the non href text and the link opens up if i create this with puppeteer pdf creation.
I tried with

```
white-space: nowrap
```

but that only prevents line break but I need the line break inside the link if they are too long.

```
<p>fdsfsdfsdfsdf 
<a href="https://google.de" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(77, 77, 77);"> 
<strong>Testlink so long dsdsdfsd dfdsfsdfdsf f fdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdffdsfsd        fdsddddddddddddddddddfdsfdfdsf  fdsfdfdsfdsfsdfdsf</strong>
</a></p>
```

I added a picture to see the html markup from console that shows how it is working for puppeteer.
[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of broken code including CSS and markup so we can properly debug.

Comment: There is no CSS for this part only that markup from above inside a div.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Works fine in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xqv2swo1/ Inspect element and have a look at all inherited css and then share that. Probably going to be a line-height issue

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of the bug, I just copy pasted your code in a new codepen and added a p {max-width:200px} and the problem you describe doesn't exist. Did you check different browsers?

Comment: It seems that the error only occurs in Chrome, for Firefox everything is ok so must be some Chrome related issue. Do you have any idea why it is not working for Chrome and maybe how to fix it?

Comment: If it works in Firefox it should work in Chrome, both are webkit browsers. Have you tried deleting cache in chrome (esp if that's your primary browser)

Comment: Ok it is working for now. But the following error is I create a PDF with Puppeteer from that and the link is over the complete area like it is shown in the browser above. So not only the link text. Why is there a difference? Isnt it the same cause of chromium?